# Finding he largest palindromic number, which is the product of two simple (prime) five-digit numbers. Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was trying to write a program that returns the largest palindromic number, which is the product of two simple five-digit numbers, and returns the factors themselves.

A prime number is a natural number that is divided only by 1 and itself (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...)

A palindromic number reads the same both ways (for example, ABBA).

```
if(isPalin(mul) && isPrime(i) && isPrime(j))

function isPrime(i){
  for (var k = 2; k <= i; k++) {
      if (i%k===0 && i!==k) {
          return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}



<!--code-->


<script>

function largestPalindrome(){

    for(var i = 99999; i>10000; i--){
        for(var j = 99999; j>10000; j--){
            var mul = j*i;
            if(isPalin(mul) && isPrime(i) && isPrime(j)){
                return i * j;


            }
        }

    }
}


function isPalin(i){
    return i.toString() == i.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
    }

function isPrime(i){
  for (var k = 2; k <= i; k++) {
      if (i%k===0 && i!==k) {
          return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}

console.log(largestPalindrome());

</script>
```

When I run this program it does not display anything in the console and I am not sure why.

Comment: Time complexity of your code is `O(n^3)` which for `n = 10^4` it takes too long. print something in your isPrime and other functions to sure it progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem::  **Time Complexity**

#### improvements

1. isPrime()

   ```
   function isPrime(n)
   {
       // Corner cases
       if (n <= 1)  return false;
       if (n <= 3)  return true;

       // This is checked so that we can skip 
       // middle five numbers in below loop
       if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

       for (var i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6)
           if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
              return false;

       return true;
   }
   ```

   you `isprime` function is not optimized one. You should use this.
2. Don't find every prime number 2 times.!  Just find all prime numbers once, store them into a list, and then pick every number from prime list and check if it is palindrome.

   ```
   var primelist = [];
   for(var i = 99999; i > 10000; i++)
   {
        if(isprime(i))
        {
             primelist.push(i);
        }
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < primelist.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < primelist.length; j++) 
       {
            if(isPalindrome(i*j))
            {
                // Number you want.

                return (i*j);
            }
       }  
   }
   ```
3. to check , start from the largest prime numbers.
4. a 5 digit number starts from 10000 to 99999 instead of 11111 to 99999. Although, It does not change the output of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Look this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for time-complexity of algorithms. Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to see how time-complexity can influence to your program efficiency.

This part is not very precise but it can help. Your first loop runs `99999-10000` time. Also this holds for second loop. The `isPrime` in the worst case runs `(99999)`. So `if (i%k===0 && i!==k) return false;` runs `total_ops = (99999-10000)^2*(99999)` times(we skip other part of your code). If your program written in c++ which is more faster than java-script it can run about `2*(10^8)` *simple* operation per second. Your program run time is about(obviously more than) `total_ops/(2*10^8)` (I suggest calculate it to have an estimation...).

**PS:** You can put print to your functions to ensure about their progress...