# Find the largest palindrome which is product of two 5-digit prime numbers, where is the mistake

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, sympy

I try to find the largest palindrome which is product of two 5-digit prime numbers. The program also have to return the multipliers. The problem is that the program works for a very long time and gives the wrong result. Where is the mistake and How I can correct it?

```
from sympy import sieve
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_combinations
from numpy import prod

def max_palindrome(prime_numbers):
    prime_numbers_list_unique_combinations = multiset_combinations(prime_numbers, 2)
    list_palindromes = ((prod(i), i) for i in prime_numbers_list_unique_combinations if \
                        str(prod(i)) == str(prod(i))[::-1])
    result = max(list_palindromes)
    return "The max palindrome is {0} which is producted of {1} and {2} numbers".format(result[0],\
                                                                                        result[1][0], result[1][1])

from timeit import default_timer
start = default_timer()

print max_palindrome((i for i in sieve.primerange(9999, 99999)))
# My wrong result: The max palindrome is 1997667991 which is producted of 69143 and 91009 numbers

end = default_timer()
print "The time of max_palindrome program's execution is {} sec".format(end - start)
# The time of max_palindrome program's execution is 876.579393732 sec
```

Comment: Why are primes related here? Can you explain your code?

Comment: Why do you use primes? A number can be a palindrome without being a prime no? Yeah no idea for the down vote. I actually upvoted...

Comment: (why so many downvotes? I don't think this is too bad a question, apart from the OP not saying the error is on which line, and attempt to allocate a tuple with size something like 10^10)

Comment: @Mathieu Still, I don't think this is not a very good question, either (too localized, unlikely to help anyone else). You should only upvote if the question is good, not to "counteract the downvotes".

Comment: The problem is interesting.  But may I ask why do you need this? I'm curious. Also I agree that there is no reason this should be so harshly downvoted

Comment: @Olivier Probably some programming exercises. But the OP knows how to use numpy and sympy, and don't know to use generator function instead of tuple ...

Comment: @user202729 yea... Makes me think of this amasad.me/intuition

Comment: (side note: You may want to specify explicitly that you're using Python 2. Python 2 and Python 3 are different) [tag:python-2.7]

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263430/memoryerror-while-using-range-in-python-2-7-4) about memory error. tl;dr: Use generator expression / iterator instead of trying to store them all in the memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding he largest palindromic number, which is the product of two simple (prime) five-digit numbers. Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617941/finding-he-largest-palindromic-number-which-is-the-product-of-two-simple-prime)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `generators` to chain your operations lazily, otherwise you will be storing huge lists.

First we need to recover the primes.

```
import math

def find_primes(n):
    # Prepare our Sieve, for readability we make index match the number by adding 0 and 1
    primes = [False] * 2 + [True] * (n - 1)

    # Remove non-primes
    for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if primes[x]:
            primes[2*x::x] = [False] * (n // x - 1)

    return [x for x, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime]
```

Then to keep from memory errors, we make sure to keep everything a generator.

```
import itertools

def find_palindrome(n):
    # Those all output generators instead of lists
    primes = find_primes(n)
    factors = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(primes, 2)
    products = ((p * q, p, q) for p, q in factors)
    palindromes = ((pal, p, q) for pal, p, q in products if is_palindrome(pal))

    try:
        return max(palindromes)
    except ValueError:
        # No palindrome exists
        return None
```

Profit.

```
find_palindrome(99999) # (999949999, 30109, 33211)
```

Running time is around 25 seconds with *Intel i5-2500K*.

Comment: (side note: the `find_primes` can be replaced with the `sieve.primerange` function)

Comment: I really like my slicing based sieve though

Comment: Also -- I don't think that `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` iterates in decreasing product order. You will probably get `99991×10007` before `99989×99989`.

Comment: I agree, but how I could return the multipliers of this max palindrome?

Comment: My solution: Palindrome: 1997667991 which is producted of 69143 and 91009 numbers

Comment: And your answer is wrong: 69143 * 91009 = 6292635287

Comment: I added a basic benchmark at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We start from largest palindrome and check if it has 5-digit prime divisors. Next we can take previous palindrome and so on (sorry but example in JavaScript):

```
const MAX_DIVISOR = 99999;
const MIN_DIVISOR = 10000;

function isPalindrome(number) {
    let rebmun = 0;
    let remainder = number;
    while (remainder !== 0) {
        let lastDigit = remainder % 10;
        rebmun = rebmun * 10 + lastDigit;
        remainder = (remainder - lastDigit) / 10;
    }
    return number === rebmun;
}

function getPrimeDivisors(oddNumber) {
    if (oddNumber % 2 === 0) return [];

    for (let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(oddNumber); i += 2) {
        if (oddNumber % i === 0) {
            if (i < MIN_DIVISOR) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return [i, oddNumber / i];
            }
        }
    }

    return [];
}

function getMaxPalindrome(fromOdd) {
    while (!isPalindrome(fromOdd)) {
        fromOdd -= 2;
    }
    return fromOdd;
}

function getPrevPalindrome(palindrome) {
    function digitsCount(number) {
        let count = 0;
        while (number !== 0) {
            count++;
            number = ~~(number / 10);
        }
        return count;
    }

    function calcPalindrome(num, count) {
        let partToMerge = count % 2 ? ~~(num / 10) : num;
        while (partToMerge) {
            let lastDigit = partToMerge % 10;
            num = num * 10 + lastDigit;
            partToMerge = (partToMerge - lastDigit) / 10;
        }
        return num;
    }

    const palindromeLength = digitsCount(palindrome);
    const newFirstPart = ~~(palindrome / Math.pow(10, ~~(palindromeLength / 2))) - 1;
    const prevPalindrome = calcPalindrome(newFirstPart, palindromeLength);
    return palindromeLength > digitsCount(prevPalindrome) ? (prevPalindrome * 10 + 9) : prevPalindrome;
}

function main() {
    let palindrome = getMaxPalindrome(MAX_DIVISOR * MAX_DIVISOR);
    let divisors = getPrimeDivisors(palindrome);
    while (divisors.length !== 2) {
        palindrome = getPrevPalindrome(palindrome);
        divisors = getPrimeDivisors(palindrome);
    }
    return {palindrome, divisors};
}
```